# Can led christmas lights flash on and off when they are completely unplugged from the wall?? I am not sure how my lights are doing this

Tags: lighting

Can led christmas lights flash on and off when they are completely unplugged from the wall??  I am not sure how my lights are doing this and usually late at nite, i can not find a logical reason...if anyone has ideas as to how or why this can happen ??

Comment: Any chance there's a practical joker involved?

Comment: I've seen my one home-made lighting fixture sometimes stay on for several seconds after it's turned off at the switch. I assume that in the ballast there might be some capacitors that aren't fully discharged. It would be weird if your lights come on after being unplugged for a long time.

Comment: are they battery powered?